# Internal server error 500 when Laravel project was uploded to 000webhost server

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment

Good day to all, I faced the issue: Internal server error 500 when I uploaded all folders and files of my Laravel project to 000webhost server. Moreover, as I read some articles helping to solve my problem I found out that I need to change php configuration to 7.2 but unfortunately 000webhost recently changed its web design and I cannot find cpanel thanks to which it is possible to ensure that 7.2 version of PHP is used. If anyone has ever encountered such problem, pleaseee help

Comment: The PHP version should not be an issue as long as its supported by the webhost, while some older PHP versions are deprecated, they aren't entirely removed yet.

Comment: @Martin, look what people suggest doing "For anyone scratching their heads about a 500 internal server error, be careful that your hosting isn't running php 7.0 or older.

I fixed this issue after a whole day of attempts by simply going to cpanel -> php configuration -> use PHP version 7.2.

Seriously, the 500 internal error sucks."

Comment: check folder permission for storage and bootstrap. what your laravel version and php version inserver?